# trigger mutating error

Tags: sql, oracle, triggers, mutating-table

I have emp table in schema1 and emp_fianl in schema2.

```
emp  
empid  ename  estatus
1      abc    incomplete
2      xyz    complete
3      ifg    incomplete
4      mno    incomplete

Emp_final
empid  ename  estatus
2      xyz    complete
```

I have to create a trigger to insert data in Schema2 emp_final table when the estatus in schema1 emp table changes to complete.
I have written below trigger for the same:

```
Create or replace trigger tri_emp_final  
After update on emp  
BEGIN  
IF :new.estatus='complete' then
Insert into emp_final  
(select :old.empid,:old.ename,:new.estatus from schem1.emp);  
END IF;  
END;  
/
```

I am getting mutating error message for the above code. When I am trying to update the status in emp table. I am a java developer and do not have much experience in Oracle, SQL. Can anyone please help?

Comment: Try before update instead of after update

Comment: You already have values in pseudo-columns :old.empid, :old.name and :new.estatus, there is no need to select anything from schem1.emp table. That query is wrong - if it worked, it would have inserted the same data into table emp_final for every single row in the schem1.emp table.

Comment: Its not getting inserted in the emp_final table

Comment: If you think trigger is not working as expected than add some logging and check what happens. Are you sure that estatus is being changed to 'complete'?

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
Create or replace trigger tri_emp_final  
After update on emp  for each row
BEGIN  
  IF :new.estatus='complete' then
    Insert into emp_final ( empid , ename , estatus)
    Values
    (:old.empid,:old.ename,:new.estatus );  
  END IF;  
END;  
/
```

---

You can find a working demo [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/9be5f/2)

Comment: I am getting [Error] Compilation (1: 27): ORA-04082: NEW or OLD references not allowed in table level triggers

Comment: The trigger must be `for each row`, I've updated the answer.

Comment: thanks   now i am getting ORA-04098: trigger 'TR_ODS.UPDATE_TEST_TRIG' is invalid and failed re-validation

Comment: Please run `create trigger ....` command, and then `show errors` the latter one will display all compilation errors.

Comment: Data is not getting inserted in the table.

Comment: Trigger is getting created without any error. But the data is not getting inserted in the emp_final table.

Comment: I've tested a trigger from my answer on SQLFilddle and it works fine, I've attached a link to the working demo.

Answer (score 0):

First thing: we you want to use :old and :new, your trigger MUST be FOR EACH ROW. So you need to change : `before update on emp  for each row.` 
Second: like  Goran Stefanović wrote, you don't make that select to insert, just use the :old values.